# Split/Fill intermediate blanks with top and bottom value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column which is run over by a for loop. There are two rows with space between them, and when the first one hits the other (since it checks if value = "") it stops.

It looks like this:

```
-First person






-Second person
```

And it should turn out like this:

```
-First person
-First person
-First person
-First person
-First person
-Second person
-Second person
-Second person
-Second person
```

Code:

```
Sub FyllUtKjoenn()
    Dim sluttrad As Integer
    sluttrad = Cells(3000, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 5 To sluttrad
        If Cells(x, 1).Value = "" Then
            Cells(x, 1).Value = Cells(x - 1, 1).Value

        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Where did all the extra *'-Second person'* entries come from?

Comment: Are you just looking to fill the empty spaces with the Person above that line? Or are you filling in the empty space between 2 names with both names and meeting in the middle?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that is descriptive of the problem you're having or the question you're asking. Being in a hurry is not an excuse for writing a poor question here. If you've got the time to ask for help, you've got the time to do so properly. You're asking us to spend our time helping you solve your problem; the least you can do is make the question clear and useful to future readers here in the process. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will needs a loop at all; just a little maths. While you won't notice on a small portion of the worksheet, larger sections of looping through individual cells will slow you down.

```
Sub fill_Intermediate()
    Dim rw1 As Long, rw2 As Long

    With Worksheets("sheet5")
        rw1 = 5
        rw2 = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        'alternate
        'rw2 = .Cells(rw1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
        .Cells(rw1, 1).Resize(CLng((rw2 - rw1) / 2) + 1, 1).FillDown
        .Cells(rw2, 1).Offset(-CLng((rw2 - rw1) / 2) + 1, 0).Resize(CLng((rw2 - rw1) / 2), 1) = _
            .Cells(rw2, 1).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: first_second_person]

Answer (score 0):

sluttrad is always 1, so change `sluttrad = Cells(3000, 1).End(xlUp).Row`. Try

```
sluttrad = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], _
 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```